# Sorting numpy vector with matrix

Tags: python, sorting, numpy, matrix, vector

I have written this piece of code:

```
w = Dist.argsort(kind='mergesort');
return y[w];
```

where `w` is MxN matrix, and `y` is Nx1 vector.
Everything works fine if shape returned by `np.shape(y)` is (3,). However, when I try to input a vector of shape(3,1), my function returns a 3-dimensional MXNx1 matrix.

Is there a way to reduce (N,1) vector to (N,) size? Or to normalize output of the function for (N,1) vectors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reduce an (N,1) numpy array to (N,) with `flatten`:

```
>>>np.zeros((3, 1)).shape
(3, 1)

>>>np.zeros((3, 1)).flatten().shape
(3,)
```